# Apply Function or Lambda to Pandas GROUPBY

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, statsmodels, pandas-groupby

I would like to apply a specific function (in this case a logit model) to a dataframe which can be grouped (by the variable "model").  I know the task can be performed through a loop, however I believe this to be inefficient at best.  Example code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,10)),columns=list('abcdefghij'))
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,10)),columns=list('abcdefghij'))
df1['model']=1
df1['target']=np.random.randint(2,size=100)
df2['model']=2
df2['target']=np.random.randint(2,size=100)
data=pd.concat([df1,df2])
### Clunky, but works...  
for i in range(1,2+1):
    lm=sm.Logit(data[data['model']==i]['target'],
                sm.add_constant(data[data['model']==i].drop(['target'],axis=1))).fit(disp=0)
    print(lm.summary2())
### Can this work?  
def elegant(self):
    lm=sm.Logit(data['target'],
                sm.add_constant(data.drop(['target'],axis=1))).fit(disp=0)
better=data.groupby(['model']).apply(elegant)
```

If the above groupby can work, is this a more efficient way to perform than looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work:

```
def elegant(df):
lm = sm.Logit(df['target'],
              sm.add_constant(df.drop(['target'],axis=1))).fit(disp=0)
return lm 

better = data.groupby('model').apply(elegant)
```

Using `.apply` you passe the dataframe groups to the function `elegant` so `elegant` has to take a dataframe as the first argument here. Also your function needs to return the result of your calculation `lm`.

For more complexe functions the following structure can be used:

```
def some_fun(df, kw_param=1):
# some calculations to df using kw_param
return df

better = data.groupby('model').apply(lambda group: some_func(group, kw_param=99))
```

Comment: Okay, so using the first function would return the statsmodels object to a series.  I can then iterate through that series to print/further manipulate.  In general, do you feel this is a better approach than looping?  I would assume it to only need to pass through the data once, versus cycling through and subsetting by "i" and this would be my time saver.

Comment: Another approach that I find readable (when you have complex functions) while rather efficient is to iterate through the groups like this:
for name, group in df.groupby('model'):
    # name will be the `model` value (1 or 2)
    # group will be a dataframe group
link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups